# Изменение переменной в методе java

Tags: java

хотел бы изменить одну переменную в одном методе, но к сожалению всё вот так просто я сделать не могу.
Пытался использовать как-то рефлексию, но особо не дало успеха.

Сейчас попробую объяснить суть более понятно.

Смотрите, есть метод к примеру:

```
public void test(float yaw){
float i = yaw + 180;
}
```

Как видите там есть переменная i, и мне нужно её как-то изменить на свою, которая мне нужна.
Возможно я, чтото не знаю про рефлексию и не особо знаю как это делать, но раньше такого мне не доводилось делать. Я, конечно, не уверен, что это нужно делать именно через рефликсию.

Если, кто знает как можно - сделать или через, что то пишите, буду благодарен любой помощи.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что надо получить в результате?

Comment: Нужно просто изменить переменную i на своё число.

Comment: рассказав то же самое, что и в вопросе, слегка переставив слова, вы не добавили ясности. Что значит "изменить на свое число"? что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Смотри, мне просто нужно сделать к примеру, чтобы i = 1;, т.е еслиб я не менял, то значение было бы к примеру 181.
Т.е как я уже и говорил, сменить на своё значение переменную i, разницы на какое именно нету, главное, чтобы можно было это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас метод должен быть не void, а с возвращаемым параметром, что бы результат метода можно было присвоить, а так вы пишите метод, где происходит некий процесс, и сразу же там забывается, почитайте еще о видимости переменных. Ну или переменную `yaw` сделать глобальной

Comment: Я делал этот пример как комментарий, понятно дело, что в программе это будет как мёртвый код. 
Просто мне ведь нужно было как-то объяснить что именно переменную i нужно изменить на своё значение.

Comment: @Drew1337 я не зря упомянул про области видимости. Вы создаете переменную в методе,там ей действительно присваивается значение, но метод завершается, и Ваша переменная уже не существует